# Error App\\Application when upgrading version of CakePHP from 3.6 to 3.7

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My application is working if the version of my cake is 3.6.7 then after upgrading it to version 3.7.* it causes an error when running my application.

here's the error at apache:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Application' not found
>   in /var/www/html/test/webroot/index.php:37\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n 
>   thrown

Comment: Have you re-run `composer.phar update` already? And you still have an Application class in `src/Application.php` (that should have been added in 3.3)?

Comment: yap still not working